# Retrieve JSON redirected to localhost - Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to retrive JSON data which will be redirected to my localhost by POST method.
**Controller from SpringBoot API will be validating the contents of JSON and then forward it to my localhost.**
I only have to intercept that JSON data when thrown and display it.

I have below working code which requests the data from the API(which is not needed).I'm not getting the logic to code for above mentioned scenario.

**Component.ts:**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private posting: MyDataService
  ) {

    console.log(window.location.href);
  }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.posting.postMethod(formData)
      .subscribe(

      res => console.log(res),
      err => alert("Pokemon failed to come out"),

      )   }
```

**Service.ts:**

```
@Injectable()

export class MyDataService {

  constructor(private http: Http)
  { }

 postMethod(data:FormData ):Observable<any>{ 
    return this.http.post("http://ABCXYZ", data)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(err=>Observable.throw(err))
  }}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Not getting the code/logic on how to intercept the JSON data redirected by backend API towards the localhost and then display it. We normally request the data from backend and then work on it.In my case, it is sending me the data without requesting and I need to capture that JSON data and display it

Comment: What do you mean by intercept? Would an HttpInterceptor work?

Comment: Can you clarify more? If I understand correctly, you want to post data from your web browser (client) to an API (server A), which then forwards it to localhost (server B), before returning finally to the client? So the round trip would look like `Client > A > B > A > Client`?

Comment: @J.Pichardo Intercept meant that we won't know when the API would send the JSON data to localhost but whenever it does, we should be ready to capture, store & display the data.

Comment: @Squiggle Consider a login attempt for example: when client clicks on login on a webpage, the login info would be sent through JSON to SpringBoot where it will validate the user,if it returns true, the same JSON would then be forwarded to localhost where it will be captured and then worked on(displayed for example).

Comment: It sounds like you're describing federated identity - e.g. OpenID Connect - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID_Connect - and then trying to mix in some other responsibilities.
There are existing patterns, standards and libraries for this approach of communicating between Browser, Authentication Provider and API.
You'll discover that the communication between SpringBoot and "localhost" is difficult-if-not-impossible to perform in a sensible, secure manner. My advice is to find another approach.

Comment: I believe,I confused you and myself at same time with "local host": What I really wanted to say is when client clicks on login on a webpage, the login info would be sent through JSON to SpringBoot where it will validate the user,if it returns true, the same JSON would then be `forwarded back to webpage`, where it will be captured and then worked on(displayed for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50446204/angular-5-receive-post-requests) to this question.
In short, Angular won't be able to make the above requests.